# VSTS Continuous Delivery to non-Azure web server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

It doesn't look like this is possible but is there a way to use VSTS Continuous Delivery and deploy to a server outside Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. VSTS Continuous Delivery can deploy to anything that can run the VSTS agent or anything that can be targetted from a VSTS agent. Basically you have two options:

1. Let the VSTS (hosted) agent communicate directly to your deployment target. Out of the box tasks can [use MsDeploy or WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=vsts). There are also tasks for Octopus Deploy, AWS and other systems available through the Marketplace. Powershell has options to connect directly to other systems and you can use many different protocols from a powershell script.
2. Install the VSTS agent on your target machine (or network). The VSTS agent can be downloaded and installed onto the target server. That way you have full local access to the target machine and can simply copy the files to the target folder straight from the Release Management artefacts. By installing a VSTS agent in you local network, you can use the options listed under 1 to bypass firewalls that might be blocking the hosted agent.